# Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()

Tags: magento-1.9, error

> Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()
>   in
>   /home/vithauix/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line

Comment: That means `getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()` is not written in `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data.php` file. How are you calling this method?

Comment: I have check on magento C.E  1.9 this function exit.. may your installation file issue

Comment: When does this occur? What did you change?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

`Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()` was introduced in Magento 1.9, so it sounds like your `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data` class is from an older version.

The most likely explanation is an override in `app/code/local`. Remove `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php` or replace it with `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php` and re-apply your modifications.

Note that code pool overrides in `app/code/local/Mage` are bad practice and avoidable in almost all cases. If you really need to change a method of this helper, use a custom module with a class rewrite instead. This way, you can extend the original class and only change selected methods, which is more update-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Default Magento helper class `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data` has a method `getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()`. So I smell a core hack here or something happened with default helper class.

First check whether, you have a copy of this class in the local pool. ie at `app\code\local\Mage\Customer\Helper\Data.php`.If such file does exist, then you should replace that file with default file which ***[you can find it here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php)***. Beware this step, because this may completely remove all customization that you have performed to that file from the local codepool. So it is your job to include those customization too. For that you can compare your local codepool file with the default file (which I have provided in that link).

If no such file exist, you should replace the original `Data.php` file with the file which I have mentioned. The core file location is at `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Helper\Data.php`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If this file has the old content it smells like an update. And in this case I highly recommend to overwrite EVERYTHING because you can't be sure that there isn't another file which is not updated.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt absolutely right. But no clue for update in the question. If he did an update, your comment gonna smash. Hey yogesh, roger ^^^^ comment  :-)

Comment: Funny enough...  I just downloaded 1.9.0.1 because of this exact same error.  This function does not exist in the core code.  Must be a bug in this release. As I went through the release archives, it's first found in 1.9.1.0